# Python convert 150000000 to 150M

Tags: python

For example I would like to display:

- 100000000 as 100M
- 50000000 as 50M
- 500000 as 0.5M

What's the best way to do this? If something like this has been asked and answered, let me know. I wasn't 100% sure how to phrase this question while searching, so I may have missed it.

Comment: Divide by a million and put `M` in the output string

Comment: Really simple. Thanks you!

Comment: Just be sure, if it's an integer you'll need to convert it to a float or else you'll get `0M` for the last example.